# I don't get POST variables sended by an Android app (ssl https related)

Tags: android, ssl

The app worked fine before adding a certificate from startSSL.com to my server.
The POST array is empty on the server. And I don't get any error, I get response from the server.

This is the code I use to make my server calls in AsyncTasks.

```
    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST

            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            //String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
           // url += "?" + paramString;

            for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : params) { // modificado para usar URIS
                url += "/" + nameValuePair.getValue();
            }
            Log.d("Intentando conectar con el servidor: ", url);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2011/12/using-custom-certificate-trust-store-on.html

Comment: I have checked and startCom is a trusted CA by Android

Comment: DONE. It was a server isue. Removing the 'www' part from the url solved it. I configured my server with no www but I didn't imagine it was going to make me sweat this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a server isue. Removing the 'www' part from the url solved it. I configured my server with no www but I didn't imagine it was going to make me sweat this way.